# How to make the display value and selected value different for an sj autocompleter as selectbox?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

We are using the Sj:Autocompleter tag (with selectbox=true). Here, we have to show a different value in the listed data (display text) and when user clicks on any of those, the selected data's value should be populated in the autocompleter text box.

How can we acheive using the sj:autocompleter with selectbox=true ?

Example:

Following will be the listed data (ListValues) from the autocomplater

```
    "Apple - Known for it's innovative Design"       
    "MicroSoft - Known for it's usability    "       
    "Intel - Known for it's processors       "
```

When i select any of these text, we want just "Apple" or "Microsoft" or "Intel" to be populated in the sj:autocompleter text. We have kept these text as the listKeys.

On Select of the List value I want to show list key in the select box.

If so can any one tell me how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

we were able to make it by subscribing to the onSelectTopics, intercepting it and over-ridding the value.

Step 1: Subscribe to the onSelectTopics of the sj:select box  
Step 2: Write the javascript function which will get invoked during onSelectTopics  
Step 3: set data.item.value='melon';

```
 <sj:select
                    name="fruitFamily"
                    href="%{fruitFamilyList}"
                    formIds="mainform"
                    list="fruitsList"
                    listKey="fruitFamily"
                    listValue="fruitFamily"
                    parentTheme="simple"
                    autocomplete="true"
                    selectBoxIcon="true"
                    cssClass="selectBox"
                    loadingText="user defined loading...."
                    onSelectTopics="check"/>

$.subscribe('check', function(event,data)
{
    data.item.value='melon';
    });
```